# Marcar primer radio button siempre - HTML

Tags: php, html

Dispongo de un visualización de opiniones y quiero que se marque SIEMPRE la que esté en primera posición, exista o no, en la siguiente actualización de la visualización.

De inicio se me marca la primera, debido a que tengo `if($opinion["idopinion"]==1){` y casualmente coincide con el idopinion==1 de la base de datos, pero no tendría que ser así. **¿Cómo se soluciona?**

Si pulso "Eliminar" esa opinión, se recarga la página pero no marca ningún radiobutton. **¿Cómo se arreglaría?**

**Código:**

```
if(isset($_GET["eliminar"])){
    //Llamamos al método "obtenerOpinionesPorCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro del email del cliente.
    $opiniones = BD::obtenerOpinionesPorCliente("desiree@hotmail.com");
    echo "<form action='menu_cliente.php?eliminar=1' name='form_a_eliminar' id='form_a_eliminar' method='POST'>";
        foreach ($opiniones as $opinion){
            $fecha = new DateTime($opinion["fecha"]);
            $comentario = $fecha->format('d/m/Y')."(".$opinion["idemail"].") - ".$opinion["opinion"]."<br/><br/>";
            if($opinion["idopinion"]==1){
                echo "<input type='radio' name='a_eliminar' value='".$opinion["idopinion"]."' checked>".$comentario."</input>";
            }else{
                echo "<input type='radio' name='a_eliminar' value='".$opinion["idopinion"]."'>".$comentario."</input>";
            }
        }
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Eliminar opinion' name='eliminar_opinion' id='eliminar_opinion'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

**Función: obtenerOpinionesPorCliente:**

```
   static public function obtenerOpinionesPorCliente($idemail){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM opiniones WHERE idemail='$idemail';";
        $registro = $ejecucion->query($sql);
        //Creamos un array para almacenar las opiniones.
        $misopiniones = array();
        //Recorremos el array y añadimos en él las opiniones mediante array_push.
        while($datos = $registro->fetch()){
            //Al array $misopiniones le pasamos $datos.
            array_push($misopiniones, $datos);
        }
        //Devuelve el array $misopiniones (asociativo).
        return $misopiniones; 
    }
```

**Código base de datos:**

```
CREATE TABLE OPINIONES (
    idopinion INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    idemail VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    idcabana INT NOT NULL, 
    opinion VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    valoracion INT NOT NULL,
    CHECK (valoracion>=0 AND valoracion<=5),
    FOREIGN KEY (idemail) REFERENCES CLIENTES(idemail) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (idcabana) REFERENCES CABANAS(idcabana) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**Button Eliminar:**

```
    if(isset($_POST["eliminar_opinion"])){
        $a_eliminar = $_POST["a_eliminar"];
        //Llamamos al método "borrarOpinion" y le pasamos el parámetro (idopinion).
        BD::borrarOpinion($a_eliminar);
    }
```

Al eliminar una opinión, no se marca ninguna debido a que no existe la idopinion==1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el html?, posiblemente la solución esté en referenciar en base al primer hijo del elemento que contenga las opiniones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin pensar mucho, la primera idea que se me ocurre es usar un flag:

```
if(isset($_GET["eliminar"])){
    //Llamamos al método "obtenerOpinionesPorCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro del email del cliente.
    $opiniones = BD::obtenerOpinionesPorCliente("desiree@hotmail.com");
    echo "<form action='menu_cliente.php?eliminar=1' name='form_a_eliminar' id='form_a_eliminar' method='POST'>";
        $selected = true;
        foreach ($opiniones as $opinion){
            $fecha = new DateTime($opinion["fecha"]);
            $comentario = $fecha->format('d/m/Y')."(".$opinion["idemail"].") - ".$opinion["opinion"]."<br/><br/>";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='a_eliminar' value='".$opinion["idopinion"]."' ".($selected?"checked":"").">".$comentario."</input>";
            $selected = false;

        }
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Eliminar opinion' name='eliminar_opinion' id='eliminar_opinion'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Comment: De esta forma, se me marca el último, no el primero.

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo mediante jQuery. Accedes al `#form_a_eliminar` y buscas el primer radio button:

```
$("#form_a_eliminar input:radio[disabled=false]:first").attr('checked', true);
```

Esto funciona independientemente del `name`, `id`, `value`... que tenga el input del radiobutton.

Comment: he añadido $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#form_a_eliminar input:radio[disabled=false]:first").attr('checked', true);
}); a un fichero externo .js y tampoco me funciona.